# processing image uploaded by createview in django

Tags: django

I am returning back to django after a while, and I am a bit confused on how I should go about processing images once they have been uploaded in createview class.

So, I have this:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email_simple = models.EmailField(max_length = 256)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

```
class SomeModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Form for the image model"""
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('full_name', 'email_simple', 'image')
```

```
<form role="form" action="{% url 'upload' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
 <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

It works fine as in uploads the image, but, before redirecing to say an upload done page, I would like to postprocess this image using custom logic (such as resizing using ffmpeg and processing it further). Which method within CreateView can allow me to do this? or is there a more efficient way to approach this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save()
    imag = Image.open(instance.image.path)
    output_size = (400, 300)  # new size
    imag.thumbnail(output_size)
    imag.save(instance.image.path)
```

Comment: See [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.